# Can i keep hardcoded credential of picasa in my app and user upload photo to my account

Tags: android, picasa

Hello every one i am making a studio app in android which user can upload photo  through my app. Problem is that i don't want user have to login . When user open my app click gallary then click to upload all image should upload to my picasa account is it possible please reply .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the picassa api
https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java?hl=es#Photos

Yoy should check which options allows you to upload images but you never have to hardcode your private credentials.